# Angular Paginator issue

Tags: angular, angular9

I have an issue with items per page option in mat table, I'm using Angular 9, So when I render the table, I try to select an option that I already add in the HTML:

```
 <mat-paginator  [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" [pageSize]="10" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

Therefore, I display the table in a pop-up window, in addition, I discover that the mat select is displayed behind the pop-up windows I don't know why but I can only change the value of items per page using the keyboard arrow bottom or down as you can see in the screenshot :
[image: pic 1]
[image: pic 2]
Could you please help me to show items per page over the pop-up windows?

Answer (score 0):

what version of material are you using?
BTW, if you has a material table and a paginator in a mat-dialog, you need make the instruction

```
this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
```

After open the mat-dialog. For this, when open the mat-dialog you subscribe to afterOpened()

```
openDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
      width: '250px',
      data: ...
    });

    //After opened, you indicate that the dataSource.paginator is the "paginator"
    dialogRef.afterOpened().subscribe(res=>{
      dialogRef.componentInstance.dataSource.paginator = 
           dialogRef.componentInstance.paginator)
    })

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
        ....
    });
  }
```

Comment: I'm using material version 9.2.4 but I don't use mat-dialog